# How to convert a human date to EPOCH range that covers the entire day?

Tags: python, epoch

I am trying to convert a human-readable date to an EPOCH range, where the range covers that entire day.

I couldn't find any existing function that does it- anyone know if there is one?

Example:
So if we converted today's date (15/09/22) into EPOCH at midnight start of the day, I believe it would be 1663200000. However from 1663200000 to 1663286399 it is still today- the latter being midnight today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the python `datetime` lib.

```py
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> (dt.datetime(2022, 9, 15).timestamp(), dt.datetime(2022, 9, 16).timestamp()-1)
(1663171200.0, 1663257599.0)

# add tzinfo
>>> (dt.datetime(2022, 9, 15, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc).timestamp(), dt.datetime(2022, 9, 16, tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc).timestamp()-1)
(1663200000.0, 1663286399.0)
```

Comment: @yunzi the above starts from 4pm on 2022/09/15 to 4pm the next day. Is it possible to change it to midnight on 2022/09/15 to midnight the following day?

Comment: Would be a big help if you could suggest how to do it from midnight!

Comment: It's midnight because of timezone. You can add UTC tzinfo.